# Oracle. How to get mock data using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get dummy data using SQL - with 10 rows and 10 columns or 100x100 or other arbitrary number.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
    select
        (select * from
                (
                    select     level lvl
                    from       dual
                    connect by level <= 10
                )
            pivot (
                max(lvl)
                for lvl in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
            )
        )
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10
```

but this code throws an error

Is it possible to do this with a single SQL query?

And if not, what is the preferable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current construction is:

```
select ( select < 10 columns > ... )
from dual
connect by level <= 10
```

Oracle is expecting a single column in the subquery, not 10 (or 100).

You don't need a subquery though, you can do:

```
select * from
(
    select     level lvl
    from       dual
    connect by level <= 10
)
pivot (
    max(lvl)
    for lvl in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
)
connect by level <= 10
```

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1xq7SRr3)

Comment: Awesome! And is there a way to auto generate that sequence - "for lvl in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)".

It would be inconvenient to type sequence from 1 to 100 or more

Comment: No, not as part of this static query. You can write code to generate the static query and then run that. Depending on the data types you might be able to do something with an XML pivot but that might overcomplicate things.